# Offset of the caption relative to the picture

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, layout

There is a code in which, when you hover over the icon on the left `.leftside`, a hyperlink in the center `.centerplace` and an invisible picture on the right `.rightside` should be hidden

```js
let sidemenu = document.querySelector('#sidemenu'); // We take the block from the menu

sidemenu.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) { // We hang the handler on the menu to use delegation
  if(e.target.classList.contains('leftside')) { // If we aim at .leftside
    e.target.closest('#sidemenu').classList.add('-short'); // we take the parent of the #sidemenu and attach a handler to it
  }
}, true);

sidemenu.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('leftside')) {
    e.target.closest('#sidemenu').classList.remove('-short');
  }
}, true);
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidemenu {
  background: #afafaf;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: block;
  width: 420px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#sidemenu li {
  padding: 6px 0;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  /*display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;*/
}

#sidemenu li:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
}

#sidemenu li a {
  color: #000;
}

#sidemenu li:hover a,
#sidemenu li:hover .fa {
  color: #fff;
}

#sidemenu li .fa {
  /*margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.leftside {
  margin-left: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;  
  display: flex;
}

.rightside {
  margin-right: 16px;
  /* display: none;*/
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;  
  display: inline-flex;
}

.centerplace {
  width: 328px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*
  transition: .6s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(-328px);
  */
}

.nestedblock{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin:0 auto;
}

/*
#sidemenu.active .centerplace {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

#sidemenu{
   width: 60px;
}

#sidemenu.active{
    width: 388px;
}
*/

/* Иное состояние */

/*
.leftside:hover + .centerplace,
.leftside:hover + .centerplace + .nestedblock,
.leftside:hover + .rightside{
    display: none;
}
 */
 
#sidemenu.-short {
  flex-direction: column;
}

#sidemenu.-short .centerplace,
#sidemenu.-short .centerplace .nestedblock,
#sidemenu.-short .rightside {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- <script>
 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    let sidemenu = document.querySelector('#sidemenu');
    sidemenu.addEventListener("mouseover", checkitem);
    sidemenu.addEventListener("mouseleave", checkitem);
 
    function checkitem(event) {
        if (event.target && event.target.closest(".fa")) sidemenu.classList.add("active");
        if (event.type === "mouseleave") sidemenu.classList.remove("active");
    }
});
</script> -->

</head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.js"> -->
<body>
<ul id="sidemenu">
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Test1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Test2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Test3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>    
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Test4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>    
  </li>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="testsite3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As a result of one of the movements of the mouse cursor, the inscription becomes higher than the picture from the left side. The lettering should be at the same height as the drawing with the house. The `.nestedblock` class must align correctly.

[image: See this]

Help to achieve the correct display.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you chose bootstrap, you should understand that this is framework. I mean you should understand that you must chose only tools that it propose. And there are not those thing which you talking about. So everything another is hardcode
2. You are russian guy, why you dont use BEM?))
3. I'm not sure what did you want to match, but if I understood you correctly, here it is

   ```html
   <html>

   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

     <style>
       * {
         list-style: none;
         text-decoration: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
       }

       #sidemenu {
         background: #afafaf;
         display: inline-flex;
         /* flex-direction: column; why column if you want horizontal? */
         flex-direction: row;
         /* display: block; why you overwrite display: inlin-flex by display: block?? */
         width: 420px;
         border-right: 1px solid #000;
       }

       #sidemenu.-short {
         flex-direction: column;
       }

       #sidemenu.-short .centerplace,
       #sidemenu.-short .centerplace .nestedblock,
       #sidemenu.-short .rightside {
         display: none;
       }

       #sidemenu li {
         padding: 6px 0;
         background: #fff;
         display: flex;
         flex-shrink: 1; /* i added this */
         /*display: inline-flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-between;*/
       }

       #sidemenu li:hover {
         background: lightgreen;
         flex-shrink: 0;
         width: 328px;
         transition: 0.5s;
       }

       #sidemenu li a {
         color: #000;
       }

       #sidemenu li:hover a,
       #sidemenu li:hover .fa {
         color: #fff;
       }

       #sidemenu li .fa {
         /*margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 10px;*/
         display: inline-block;
         width: 30px;
         height: 30px;
         display: inline-flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
       }

       .leftside {
         margin-left: 16px;
         display: inline-block;
         width: 30px;
         height: 30px;
         display: flex;
       }

       .rightside {
         margin-right: 16px;
         /* display: none;*/
         visibility: hidden;
         width: 30px;
         height: 30px;
         display: inline-flex;
       }

       .centerplace {
         /* width: 328px; i removed this */
         display: inline-flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         /*
     transition: .6s;
     overflow: hidden;
     transform: translateX(-328px);
     */
       }

       .nestedblock {
         display: inline-flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         margin: 0 auto;
       }

       /*
   #sidemenu.active .centerplace {
       transform: translateX(0px);
       transition-delay: .4s;
   }

   #sidemenu{
      width: 60px;
   }

   #sidemenu.active{
       width: 388px;
   }
   */

       /* Иное состояние */

       /*
   .leftside:hover + .centerplace,
   .leftside:hover + .centerplace + .nestedblock,
   .leftside:hover + .rightside{
       display: none;
   }
    */
     </style>

     

   </head>
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.js"> -->

   <body>
     <ul id="sidemenu">
       <li>
         <div class="leftside">
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="centerplace">
           <a href="" class="nestedblock">Test1</a>
         </div>
         <div class="rightside">
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li>
         <div class="leftside">
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="centerplace">
           <a href="" class="nestedblock">Test2</a>
         </div>
         <div class="rightside">
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li>
         <div class="leftside">
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="centerplace">
           <a href="" class="nestedblock">Test3</a>
         </div>
         <div class="rightside">
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li>
         <div class="leftside">
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="centerplace">
           <a href="" class="nestedblock">Test4</a>
         </div>
         <div class="rightside">
           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
         </div>
       </li>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <script>
       let sidemenu = document.querySelector('#sidemenu'); // We take the block from the menu
     </script>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```